# Responsive slidedown height on click

Tags: jquery, slider, slide, portfolio

This is my site: http://www.stilld.nl

Scroll down to the portfolio en click on an item. 2 things happens:

1. the details for the portfolio item clicked appear underneath the portfolio,
2. The page scrolls down towards the details of that portfolio item.

This is working fine, because I make it scroll down an amount of pixels.

PROBLEM: scall down your browser and you'll see the portfolio turning into item underneath each other. Now, when you click an item it scrolls down the amount of pixels I said it had to go down, but that's not far enough right now.

MY SOLUTION (which didn't work): instead of scrolling down an number I tried scrolling down to a CLASS. This should work, but the code isn't working. It just scrolls up to the top of the page. I think this happens because the scrolling down is called upon at the same time that CLASS appears (or maybe even earlier) so maybe my code doesn't see the CLASS in time... I hope I make sence. This is my first code (and using on :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".portfolio").click(function () {
    if ($('#'+$(this).attr('target')).is(':visible')){
        $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideUp();        
    } else {
        $('.description').slideUp(); 
        $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown();        
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#targetWrapper').offset().top + 600 }, 600);
    }

});
$(".close").click(function () {
    $('.description').slideUp();        
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.p_img').offset().top }, 600);
});
```

});

WHAT I WANT:

I want this code to be transformed into a code that scrolls down to a class or ID. BUT, this has to happen after the CLASS or ID has appeared. I think that should be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**reedit**

add float:left; on div#wrapper_portfolio to have the real height of your portfolio

and change :

```
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: +($('#alldescriptions').offset().top) + 'px' }, 600);
```

Comment: Ok, this is working (check out my site). But, another problem appears with your adjustments: Click on 1 portfolio item. Scroll back up and click the next portfolio item. It scrolls down like madness, past the details!

Comment: what to you mean? What could be the thing that's triggering this effect? Because in my own code (see top op this page) this isn't the case. You could scroll up, click another portfolio item en the page would scroll down to the right height.

Comment: Look in the code inspector : the height of #wrapper_portfolio, it isnt the height of his content, so, offset.top of #alldescription is false .. that why scrollDown not work correctly...

Comment: So, how do I have to fix this?

Comment: I fixed it myself. I changed '#alldescriptions' to #targetWrapper in this line:    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: +($('#alldescriptions').offset().top) +($('#targetWrapper').height()) + 100 }, 800);   I dont know why it works, but that happens often with code... haha!

Comment: you just need to add float:left; in css property on all blocks .... your solution is dirty ... but as you want ..